# Machine hostname differs form Network (DHCP) name

Tags: networking, dhcp, openwrt, lan

I have a media streamer on which an arch linux is installed (OpenWrt). I configured the hostname of the machine to be `Streamer` but on my router dashboard, I see on the DCHP clients list that the name of the registered machine with the IP address the media streamer gets is `android-bb29fc0a53296575` instead of `Streamer`. From another linux machine when I `ping Streamer` I get the "cannot resolve hostname streamer" but when I `ping android-bb29fc0a53296575` I get a ping reply.

How can I find where this `android-bb29fc0a53296575` comes from and why the media streamer does not register with the name `Streamer` when it asks for IP address from the router by DHCP

Comment: You need to tell the local DHCP server (probably inside the OpenWRT router) to use the name you wnat. Then, you also need to tell the DNS resolver to update the name table to the set dhcp name.

Comment: @Arrow the router is not OpenWRT, the media streamer is. Moreover, how do I associate a name to the media streamer in the DHCP, does it work by mac address? Because IP address can be changed each time I reset the device (router or media streamer)

Answer (score 1):

Each computer may have any name you set in the hostname file. However, that does not mean that the local DNS resolver (or server) will use (or even know) about such set name.

To get a particular name to work in the LAN, you need to:

1. Set the name in the DHCP server.
2. Make the DNS resolver (or server) update its domain tables with the dynamic name given by DHCP.

Of course, any computer that use any other DNS server or resolver that is not aware of the above setting will fail to use the correct name.

Comment: They all use the same DNS server of the router they are connected to. I still didn't get why in the DHCP my endpoint is registered with the name android-bb29fc0a53296575 and how do I set this name for a different thing?